# Symfony query results returns empty string for working query (query with results from DB)

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

I am building custom search query for my application. Problem is that query results are empty but when I run same query (runnable query from debug) in phpMyAdmin i got expected results.

Does someoen knows where is the problem:

Here is code:

```
class ProductRepository extends EntityRepository
{
  public function findByParameters($searchParameters)
  {
      $condition = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->where('p.state LIKE :state')
        ->setParameter('state', 0);
      if(isset ($searchParameters["title"])){
        $condition
          ->andWhere('p.title LIKE :title')
          ->setParameter('title', $searchParameters["title"]);
      }
      if(isset ($searchParameters["categories"])){
        $condition
          ->andWhere('p.categories IN (:categories)')
          ->setParameter('categories', $searchParameters["categories"]);
      }
      if(isset ($searchParameters["productCondition"])){
        $condition
          ->andWhere('p.productCondition = :productCondition')
          ->setParameter('productCondition', $searchParameters["productCondition"]);
      }
      $condition
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
    return $condition;
  }
}
```

Symfony debug doctrine log:

```
SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.name AS name_2, t0.surname AS surname_3, t0.username AS username_4, t0.password AS password_5, t0.email AS email_6, t0.created AS created_7, t0.roles AS roles_8 FROM users t0 WHERE t0.id = ?
Parameters: [0 => 5]
Hide formatted query    Hide runnable query    Explain query
SELECT 
  t0.id AS id_1, 
  t0.name AS name_2, 
  t0.surname AS surname_3, 
  t0.username AS username_4, 
  t0.password AS password_5, 
  t0.email AS email_6, 
  t0.created AS created_7, 
  t0.roles AS roles_8 
FROM 
  users t0 
WHERE 
  t0.id = ?
SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.name AS name_2, t0.surname AS surname_3, t0.username AS username_4, t0.password AS password_5, t0.email AS email_6, t0.created AS created_7, t0.roles AS roles_8 FROM users t0 WHERE t0.id = 5;
```

**EDIT:**

This is runnable query from symfony debug and it is working in phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT p0_.id AS id_0, p0_.state AS state_1, p0_.title AS title_2, p0_.content AS content_3, p0_.price AS price_4, p0_.images AS images_5, p0_.created_at AS created_at_6, p0_.updated_at AS updated_at_7, p0_.expires_at AS expires_at_8, p0_.condition_id AS condition_id_9, p0_.user_id AS user_id_10 FROM product p0_ WHERE p0_.state LIKE 0 AND p0_.title LIKE 'Pc';
```

UPDATE:

```
I checked Doctrine logs and I am getting this error too:

AppBundle\Entity\Product    
The association AppBundle\Entity\Product#productCondition refers to the inverse side field AppBundle\Entity\ProductCondition#products which does not exist.
The association AppBundle\Entity\Product#user refers to the inverse side field AppBundle\Entity\User#products which does not exist.
```

Product Entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks koristi se za pokretanje određenih događaja svaki put kada entitet doživi neki lifecycle
 */
class Product implements ProductInterface
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */

    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="state", type="integer")
     */

    protected $state;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_category",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     * )
     *
     *
     * @var ArrayCollection
     */
    protected $categories;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProductCondition", inversedBy="products", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="condition_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     *
     * @var AppBundle\Entity\ProductConditionInterface
     */
    protected $productCondition;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="products", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     *
     * @var AppBundle\Entity\User
     */

    protected $user;

    /**
     * @var string $title
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=50)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = 2,
     *      max = 50,
     *      minMessage = "Title must be at least {{ limit }} characters long",
     *      maxMessage = "Title cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters"
     * )
     */

    private $title;

    /**
     * @var text $content
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text", nullable=true)
     */

    private $content;

    /**
     * @var float price
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="decimal", precision=12, scale=2)
     */

    private $price;

    /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
   */
  protected $images;


     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
     *
     * @var \DateTime
     */

    protected $createdAt;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
     *
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    protected $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
     *
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    protected $expiresAt;

    public function __construct()
   {
       $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
       $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
       $this->expiresAt = new \DateTime();
       $this->expiresAt->modify('+1 week');
       $this->state = 0;
       $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
       $this->images = array();



   }

   /**
    * Get id
    *
    * @return int
    */

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     */

    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string
     */

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set state
     *
     * @param int $state
     */

    public function setState($state)
    {
        $this->state = $state;
    }

    /**
     * Get state
     *
     * @return int
     */

    public function getState()
    {
        return $this->state;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getCategories()
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }

    /**
     * @param AppBundle\Entity\CategoryInterface $category
     *
     * @return AppBundle\Entity\ProductInterface
     */

    public function addCategory(CategoryInterface $category)
    {
        $this->categories->add($category);
    }

    /**
     * @param AppBundle\Entity\CategoryInterface $category
     *
     * @return AppBundle\Entity\ProductInterface
     */

    public function removeCategory(CategoryInterface $category)
    {
        $this->categories->removeElement($category);
    }

    /**
     * @return AppBundle\Entity\ProductConditionInterface
     */
    public function getProductCondition()
    {
        return $this->productCondition;
    }
    /**
     * @param AppBundle\Entity\ProductConditionInterface $productCondition
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\ProductConditionInterface
     */
    public function setProductCondition(ProductConditionInterface $productCondition)
    {
        $this->productCondition = $productCondition;
    }

    /**
     * @param AppBundle\Entity\User
     *
     */
    public function setUser(User $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * @return AppBundle\Entity\User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
    /**
     * @param AppBundle\Entity\ProductConditionInterface $productCondition
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\ProductConditionInterface
     */

    /**
     * Set content
     *
     * @param string $content
     */

    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;
    }

    /**
     * Get content
     *
     * @return string
     */

    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * Set content
     *
     * @param float $price
     */

    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;
    }

    /**
     * Get content
     *
     * @return float $price
     */

    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }


 /**
  * set images
  *

  */
 public function setImages($images)
 {
     $this->images = $images;
 }

 /**
  * Get images
  *
  * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
  */
 public function getImages()
 {
     return $this->images;
 }

    /**
     * Set createdAt
     *
     * @param DateTime $created_at
     */
    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTime $created_at)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $created_at;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt
     *
     * @return DateTime
     */

    public function getCreatedAt() : \DateTime
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Get getUpdatedAt
     *
     * @return DateTime
     */

    public function getUpdatedAt() : \DateTime
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set $updatedAt
     *
     * @param DateTime $updated_at
     */

    public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTime $updated_at)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updated_at;
    }

    /**
     * Get ExpiresAt
     *
     * @return DateTime
     */

    public function getExpiresAt() : \DateTime
    {
        return $this->expiresAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set $expiredAt
     *
     * @param DateTime $expired_at
     */

    public function setExpiresAt(\DateTime $expired_at)
    {
        $this->expiredAt = $expired_at;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you returning the query builder instead of the results of the query?

Comment: @Cerad I am returning results of query ($condition
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();)

Comment: return $condition; suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The debug query you have mentioned here does not match with your actual doctrine query.
If you go to Symfony profiler > Doctrine, there would be a list of queries.

If you can find the matching one with your doctrine and run that in phpmyadmin or paste it here, It would be helpful to find the problem.

Comment: Updated my questions with data you asked

Comment: Well, your query looks ok and as you said it's working fine in sql editor too and returning results from your table.

So if you are not getting anything in symfony which is weird but can you double check your doctrine file column mappings with table fields? If they map correct data types?! I noticed you are using 'LIKE 0' which might be an issue if datatype maps differently.